# OSCollector Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: linux, python, benchmark

When I tend to install and use the tool named benchmarksql-5.0, I found this problem below

```
[oracle@db01 run]$ ./runBenchmark.sh props.ora
09:43:33,081 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,083 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
09:43:33,083 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,      BenchmarkSQL v5.0
09:43:33,083 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
09:43:33,083 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2003, Raul Barbosa
09:43:33,084 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2004-2016, Denis Lussier
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2016, Jan Wieck
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, db=oracle
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, conn=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:cc
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, user=benchmarksql
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, warehouses=1
09:43:33,086 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, terminals=1
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, runTxnsPerTerminal=10
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, limitTxnsPerMin=300
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, terminalWarehouseFixed=true
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, newOrderWeight=45
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, paymentWeight=43
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, orderStatusWeight=4
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, deliveryWeight=4
09:43:33,088 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, stockLevelWeight=4
09:43:33,089 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,089 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, resultDirectory=my_result_%tY-%tm-%td_%tH%tM%tS
09:43:33,089 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorScript=./misc/os_collector_linux.py
09:43:33,089 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
09:43:33,235 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, copied props.ora to my_result_2021-12-30_094333/run.properties
09:43:33,235 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, created my_result_2021-12-30_094333/data/runInfo.csv for runID 8
09:43:33,235 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, writing per transaction results to my_result_2021-12-30_094333/data/result.csv
09:43:33,236 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorScript=./misc/os_collector_linux.py
09:43:33,236 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorInterval=1
09:43:33,236 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorSSHAddr=null
09:43:33,236 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorDevices=net_eth0 blk_sda
09:43:33,243 [main] ERROR  OSCollector : OSCollector Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at OSCollector.<init>(OSCollector.java:83)
        at jTPCC.<init>(jTPCC.java:256)
        at jTPCC.main(jTPCC.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 3 more
```

### I first seized that the solution of installing python36 and python2 by yum, but it does not help. So what should be done when occuring this error? Thanks for your comments.

For completion, when I use command `sh -x runBenchmark.sh props.ora`, the error occurred on the following command:
`java -cp '.:../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*:../lib/*:../dist/*' -Dprop=props.ora -DrunID=19 jTPCC`
The total process exhibits here

```
[oracle@db01 run]$ sh -x runBenchmark.sh props.ora
+ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
+ SEQ_FILE=./.jTPCC_run_seq.dat
+ '[' '!' -f ./.jTPCC_run_seq.dat ']'
+++ cat ./.jTPCC_run_seq.dat
++ expr 18 + 1
+ SEQ=19
+ echo 19
+ source funcs.sh props.ora
++ PROPS=props.ora
++ '[' '!' -f props.ora ']'
++ case "$(getProp db)" in
+++ getProp db
+++ grep '^db=' props.ora
+++ sed -e 's/^db=//'
+ setCP
+ case "$(getProp db)" in
++ getProp db
++ grep '^db=' props.ora
++ sed -e 's/^db=//'
+ cp='../lib/oracle/*'
+ '[' '!' -z /oracle/product/122 -a -d /oracle/product/122/lib ']'
+ cp='../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*'
+ cp='../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*:../lib/*'
+ myCP='.:../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*:../lib/*:../dist/*'
+ export myCP
+ myOPTS='-Dprop=props.ora -DrunID=19'
+ java -cp '.:../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*:../lib/*:../dist/*' -Dprop=props.ora -DrunID=19 jTPCC
13:38:18,427 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,429 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
13:38:18,429 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,      BenchmarkSQL v5.0
13:38:18,429 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
13:38:18,430 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2003, Raul Barbosa
13:38:18,430 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2004-2016, Denis Lussier
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,  (c) 2016, Jan Wieck
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, +-------------------------------------------------------------+
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, db=oracle
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
13:38:18,432 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, conn=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:cc
13:38:18,433 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, user=benchmarksql
13:38:18,433 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,433 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, warehouses=1
13:38:18,433 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, terminals=1
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, runTxnsPerTerminal=10
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, limitTxnsPerMin=300
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, terminalWarehouseFixed=true
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, newOrderWeight=45
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, paymentWeight=43
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, orderStatusWeight=4
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, deliveryWeight=4
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, stockLevelWeight=4
13:38:18,435 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,436 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, resultDirectory=my_result_%tY-%tm-%td_%tH%tM%tS
13:38:18,436 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorScript=./misc/os_collector_linux.py
13:38:18,436 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00,
13:38:18,605 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, copied props.ora to my_result_2021-12-30_133818/run.properties
13:38:18,606 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, created my_result_2021-12-30_133818/data/runInfo.csv for runID 19
13:38:18,606 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, writing per transaction results to my_result_2021-12-30_133818/data/result.csv
13:38:18,606 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorScript=./misc/os_collector_linux.py
13:38:18,607 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorInterval=1
13:38:18,607 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorSSHAddr=null
13:38:18,607 [main] INFO   jTPCC : Term-00, osCollectorDevices=net_eth0 blk_sda
13:38:18,614 [main] ERROR  OSCollector : OSCollector Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at OSCollector.<init>(OSCollector.java:83)
        at jTPCC.<init>(jTPCC.java:256)
        at jTPCC.main(jTPCC.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 3 more
```

By the way, I have tried using chmod command and sudo command to permission denied issue, but it does not help either.

Comment: It seems you don't have permissions on your file.
Try running `chmod +x ./runBenchmark.sh` first and then execute it.
If that doesn't work, you may try using sudo: `sudo ./runBenchmark.sh`

Comment: I have noticed that it occured by executing this command:
java -cp '.:../lib/oracle/*:/oracle/product/122/lib/*:../lib/*:../dist/*' -Dprop=props.ora -DrunID=14 jTPCC

Comment: I guess with **sudo** you can solution that. Maybe those paths are with root permissions or you cannot read or write from them.